# Post JSON object array to a Web API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a hard time to find a solution for this problem.
My API controller is not able to get the content of the array that I posted and is always return 0 element.

#### Model class:

```
public class Author
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int referenceId{ get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute]
    public virtual ICollection<AuthorBook> AuthorBooks { get; set; }
}

public class AuthorBook
{
    public int authorId { get; set; }
    public int bookId { get; set; }
}
```

### API controller method:

```
[Route("api/authorBooks")]
[HttpPost]
public IList getAuthorBooks(Author author)
{
    return author.AuthorBooks.ToList();
}
```

### JavaScript client:

```
 var auhtorItem =
      {
          "id": 8,
          "referenceId" : 1 ,
          "AuthorBooks": [{ authorId: 9, bookId : 23 }, { authorId: 9 , bookId  : 25}]
      };

return $.ajax({
    url: booksUrl + "authorBooks",
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(auhtorItem ),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false
});
```

I'm able to get the id and the referenceId values but the AuthorBooks is empty and the count is 0 instead of 2.

Any idea why?

Comment: Because the `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute` is present on `AuthorBooks`?

Comment: *this is not the problem. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute should not be present on AuthorBooks* and yet, there it is, in the code you're showing us. If the code you pasted here differs from the code in the actual program, [edit] the code here to match your actual problem.

Comment: `this is not the problem. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute should not be present on AuthorBooks` - then why is it present in the Code Snippet?

Comment: Hey  @degant you are right !!! but i have no choice to keep Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute other wise i will have a circular loop when i want to display the the books related to an author

Comment: @user708683 Unfortunately you will have to remove it. And to avoid a circular loop, you can create wrapper classes for requests/responses as required

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but nowhere in your code the Author is  being saved, what your method does is: receive an Author and then retrieve the Author Books, so you need to save the Author first

Comment: I dont want to save the author but only the books of the author that already exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute` attribute from the `AuthorBooks` property so that it is included during JSON serialization & deserialization:

```
public virtual ICollection<AuthorBook> AuthorBooks { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute]
public virtual ICollection<AuthorBook> AuthorBooks { get; set; }
```

You can read up more about the [`JsonIgnoreAttribute`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm) and the example alongwith it to see how it works.

Comment: Hey @degant you are right !!! Next time i will test before confirm something that im not sure of !! but i have no choice to keep Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute otherwise i will have a circular loop when i want to display the books related to an author.  Do you have an idea or an example on how to create a wrapper classes for requests/responses as required ?

Comment: @user708683 You can try something like [this](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/circular-reference-with-entity-framework-and-json-when-developing-with-asp-net-mvc) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220825/implementing-webapi-with-circular-dependencies-and-loadable-lists)

Comment: Thank you sir and have a great day :)